# Using OAuth with a Ruby on Rails application for user authentication with Twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, oauth

I ve been trying to use OAuth to authenticate users with their twitter account.
But i could not able to find any clear procedure to implement it.

I am trying to use multiple methods like http://luigimontanez.com/2010/rubyists-guide-twitter-oauth-dance/ but cannot able to find a solution.

If there is any clear tutorial for implementation could anyone please give me a hand on this?

regards,
Balane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By far the simplest way would be to just use a gem like [OmniAuth](http://www.omniauth.org/) to do this. Check out [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1).

If you still want to do it manually I can write that up for you as well, just lmk.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the last part. I get the oauth_token and oauth_token_verifier, but I don't know how to get an access token.